# Can`t understand about JQuery and some javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I can't understand why one solution works and the other doesn't. The `list` is a Map with three different values. From it, I build a structure with 3 div blocks and add an event on click. This one example doesn't work; it adds an event listener only to the last block from the list:

```js
function create_struct(list, parent){
    let _struct = new Map();
    let el;
    list.forEach((value, key, list)=>{
        el = $( "<div/>", {id: key, class: "TAB_CAPTION"}).appendTo(parent);
            el.on({
                "click": function(){
                    el.removeClass("active");
                    el.addClass("active");
                 }
            });
        _struct.set(key, el);
    });
    return _struct; 
};
```

However, this one using Map without variables works fine, and I don't understand why!

```js
function create_struct(list, parent){
    let _struct = new Map();
    let el;
    list.forEach((value, key, list)=>{
        el = $( "<div/>", {id: key, class: "TAB_CAPTION"}).appendTo(parent);
        _struct.set(key, el);
        _struct.get(key).on({
                "click": function(){
                    _struct.get(key).siblings().removeClass("active");
                    _struct.get(key).addClass("active");
            }
        });
    });
    return _struct; 
};
```

Comment: I lost you at *"however this one with using Map without variable"*. Anyway, the second one needlessly requests *things* from a Map instead of using something that is already available in a scoped variable `el`. The other question is whether or not you understand the Map.Set() and .get() methods. As a refresher: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map BTW2, the `let el;` out of scope is useless since only used inside the forEach. Define it rather in-there like `const el = $(`

Comment: This is a common mistake. There is nothing wrong with it; I made the same mistake many times. In a nutshell, you rewrite the value for the `el` variable in every iteration and move the click event handler to manipulate the latest element set to the `el`. You add an event listener to all elements, but all your event listeners modify the last one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the `el` variable inside your code?

```js
            el.on({
                "click": function(){
                    el.removeClass("active");
                    el.addClass("active");
                 }
            });
```

You reference the variable defined on the third line (`let el`). When you finish iterating the values, it will hold the last element. Every function would manipulate classes for the last value.

In a nutshell, the code adds an event listener to every element. However, the event listeners manipulate the last added element.

I suggest moving the variable definition inside the inner function block. Then you have the correct element for every click handler.

```js
function create_struct(list, parent){
    let _struct = new Map();
    list.forEach((value, key, list)=>{
        const el = $( "<div/>", {id: key, class: "TAB_CAPTION"}).appendTo(parent);
        el.on({
            "click": function(){
                el.removeClass("active");
                el.addClass("active");
             }
        });
        _struct.set(key, el);
    });
    return _struct; 
};
```

Please let me know if it works. I might make a mistake because I can not test the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. Still I don`t understand how and why, seems that I need to read something about that.